# Dynamically calculate points for user based on best submission for each task

Tags: mysql

I'm making a contest management system for competitive programming.

There will be about 100 tasks, and worst case scenario every user will post around 10 submissions for every task.

Every submission gives you some points, but only the one with the highest points for every task counts.

Now I have to implement a ranking system, but I can't figure out how to calculate their scores and sort them dynamically based on their sum of best submissions for every task.

Here are the tables I have:

> tasks: id name max_points
>
> users: id username password
>
> submissions: id task user points

The only idea I had was to add a new total_points field to the users table, and make another table to contain best submissions for every task if they want to sort by a specific task and not globally.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Start with 'rows holding the groupwise max'

Comment: Everything on Stack Overflow is a question, so the "Q:" prefix is not necessary.

Comment: @tadman Yeah, will do. I got that habit from reddit ;3

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, looks like that will do the trick. I'll respond tomorrow when I get this working :)

Comment: Okay, I got a query that works! I don't know what the complexity is though, but it's the best I can do. 

SELECT users.username, SUM(points) AS points FROM users INNER JOIN (SELECT user, MAX(points) AS points FROM submissions GROUP BY problem, user) max_pts ON users.id=user GROUP BY users.id ORDER BY points; 

Thanks @Strawberry

Comment: Doesn't really look like it's quite right yet.